# Leaflet Polylines do not show up

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a very small `SpatialLinesDataFrame` which I need to plot with `Leaflet` in `R`.

Unfortunately, for some reason I'm not able to do so.
[This](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=06960234957573386132&t=0696023495757338613263878) is the data (it's 12KB).

I try to do:

```
library(leaflet)
load("mylines.Rdata")
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolylines(data=mylines)
```

However the resulting map does not make sense, I can only see a line in the top of the screen and this is not what should be plotted.
This is the result:
[image]

Instead, If I do:

```
library(mapview)
mapview(mylines)
```

Result:
[image]
It works perfectly, despite `mapview` using `leaflet` underneath.
What am I doing wrong in the `Leaflet` syntax?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how that "line in top of the screen" looks like? What happens when you zoom out the map?

Comment: @IvanSanchez Done, I added two screenshot illustrating the problem. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Yeah, that looks like an artifact when the latitudes of the points are greater than ~85.5 degrees (because map projections are not trivial). I cannot read `.rdata` files, so I hope that folks more knowledgeable in R can have a good look at your file and check if the latitude of your data makes sense.

Comment: @IvanSanchez The coordinates of that map actually are the same as the leaflet projection, meaning that the CRS is: `+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs`. So it's not lat-lon. This may be the culprit, but then why does `mapview` work?

Comment: **leaflet** expects coordinates to be in `longlat`. Use `mylines_ll <- sp::spTransform(mylines, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))` and `mylines_ll` should be rendered correctly. **mapview** does this for you on-the-fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am used to working with `leaflet` providing `raster`s, so I usually use the `addRasterImage` function, which needs data projected over `leaflet`'s display projection (EPSG:3857). However, for polygons and lines, as @TimSalabim correctly pointed out, this is not the case.

So the solution in this case was to just not reproject the data to the `leaflet` projection beforehand, and provide it in lat-lon coordinates (EPSG:4326).

`mapview` worked since it does this automagically.